# CNContactVCardSerialization keeps throwing an error

Tags: macos, vcf-vcard, cncontact

I can't find a solution for the fact that the line with: "CNContactVCardSerialization" keeps throwing an error. Any ideas on what can be wrong here and/or how to fix it? Getting the array with CNContacts works ok.

```
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    var contacts = [CNContact]()
    var vcardFromContacts = NSData()


    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:[CNContactVCardSerialization.descriptorForRequiredKeys()])

    do{
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: {
            contact, cursor in
            contacts.append(contact)})
    } catch {
        print(">>>[ERROR] Unable to get contacts: \(error)")
    }

    // Returns the vCard representation of the specified contacts
    print(">>>[INFO ] Number of contacts found: \(contacts.count)")


    do {
        try vcardFromContacts = CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: contacts) as NSData
    } catch {
        print(">>>[ERROR] Unable to create Vcard information: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the full error output?

Comment: It reports a "nilError" in the print statement. In the error.localizeddescription the following is displayed: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)"

Comment: I'm getting this error. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I am also getting that error. Have someone solved?